# Did old Crookes Radiometers ever have a pair of terminals?

Tags: physics

This is a question about old physics lab equipment.

[This](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27118/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27124/12102) question led to the question in SciFi SE [Crookes Radiometer at the end of a telescope in old movie scene, something about a comet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187145/51174) which led to the image below.

Of course one does not use wires to couple a radiometer to a telescope.

However, my question is about the (now old, possibly then as well) [Crookes Radiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer) shown in the image from 1965. There are two terminals in the wooden base of the radiometer.

**Question:** Did old Crookes Radiometers ever have a pair of terminals? I can imagine a heater used to evaporate trace amounts of some material to adjust the pressure for teaching/demonstration purposes, or even some kind of getter pump to reduce the pressure (as some electron tubes had), but I thought I'd ask here to see if someone familliar with older lab equipment might know.

**below:** Screen shot from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTxfEWi1AYM) of Episode 3 (1965) of The Time Tunnel [The end of the World](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0723756/) after roughly `36:15`.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a tag like `equipment` or `apparatus` or something like `identify-this-object` but so far no luck.

Comment: I [originally asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404391/83380) this question in Physics SE ten months ago but there was no activity. Today I've deleted it there and posted it here instead, since migration is no longer possible.

Comment: [Crookes' Crookes Radiometer had terminals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkIif0S8PTk), but not like your image.

Comment: @KeithMcClary I'd never seen that before, thank you! Isn't it totally amazing coincidence that Crookes' Radiometer was a *Crookes Radiometer!?* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend here.  I found a forum which contained a reference to [this image](http://www.ece.drexel.edu/pix/cmf2.pdf)

which shows a barely-working generator.  Exerpt from that image:

[image: induction generator]

The forums I found generally suggested that it's pretty much impossible to get enough torque to drive any mechanically connected generator system.  So it can be done but I suspect the image you provided is a case of "Let's toss in as much cool-looking lab toys as we can."

Comment: Your answer to "Did old Crookes Radiometers ever have a pair of terminals?" is Yes, or No? Generator or torque seems incredibly specific thing to negate, and doesn't really rule out other uses. And that isn't an "old Crookes Radiometer" either.

Comment: @uhoh please explain what a pair of wires would otherwise do.  Light a bulb underneath the mechanism?

Comment: Re-read the question for *two possible* examples I've listed just to get the ball rolling. Anyway the question explains that the photo is circa 1965, so then or earlier is the timeframe to look at.